# How to display the formula field resource image using visual force in sites?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I had used this formula field to display the image from static resource.

```
IF(Lead_SCORE__c >= 0.90,IMAGE("/img/samples/stars_500.gif", "5 Stars"), 
    IF(Lead_SCORE__c >= 0.80,IMAGE("/img/samples/stars_400.gif", "4 Stars"), 
        IF(Lead_SCORE__c >= 0.70,IMAGE("/img/samples/stars_300.gif", "3 Stars"), 
            IF(Lead_SCORE__c >= 0.60,IMAGE("/img/samples/stars_200.gif", "2 Stars"), 
                IF(Lead_SCORE__c >= 0.50,IMAGE("/img/samples/stars_100.gif", "1 Star"), 
                    IMAGE("/img/samples/stars_000.gif", "0 Stars"), 
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

and i have to display the image from inner html in javascript.i had the splitted the image and passing the image variable into inner html.in page it showing correctly but i had given access to site for that visualforce that image is showing as a broken image.how to solve it. can anyboby look on this.

Comment: try to give complete URL. that might help.

Comment: I had given full url also but its showing broken image only....

Comment: @user looks this is my site and I am able to access like this  http://ap2-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/pages/img/samples/stars_500.gif

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000007604) article describing **Steps to create a Formula Field that displays an image**. Key snipets from the link below. Hope this below.

1. Create a public folder to hold your image files

   1. Click the Documents tab.
   2. Click Create New Folder.
   3. Type the folder name (e.g., "Public Images").
   4. Give users "Read-Only" access to the folder and make it accessible to all users.
2. Upload your image file to your Documents storage area

   1. Click the Documents tab.
   2. Click New.
   3. Enter the document name to be displayed on the browser.
   4. From the Folder dropdown list, select the folder you created in step #1.
   5. Click on Browse to look for and select the file to upload.
   6. Click Save.
3. Obtain the URL to the file(s) you uploaded

   1. Click the Documents tab.
   2. From the Folder dropdown list, select the folder you created in step #1.
   3. Click Go.
   4. Click on the "View" link next to the name of the file you are going to use.
       -A new browser window/tab will open.
   5. Go to the address bar, highlight and copy the URL.

Example:-

```
    IF( Amount > 100, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01570000000Q6El", "Green"),
       IF ( Amount > 50, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01570000000Q6Ef", "Yellow"),
          IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01570000000Q6Ep", "Red")))
```

Answer (score 1):

since sites are external users they cannot access contents stored in static resources since its available for authenticated internal users only. The right way to do this would be to put the images in a document folder and secure the folder security and refer the open url from the images, check the below link which gives the details

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003730&language=en_US