# Add light indicator on page layout

Tags: visualforce, formula-field, page-layout, images

I want to add red light and green light indicator on Opportunity page layout. If opportunity is in On-Hold stage then it should be Red else green.
where can i get image file? and how can i show it in page layout.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a formula field to show the images stored in Documents. Please see the below SFSE and Salesforce Help link to get a idea on this. Hope this helps.

SFSE Link - [How to display the formula field resource image using visual force in sites?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/121736/how-to-display-the-formula-field-resource-image-using-visual-force-in-sites/121784#121784)

Salesforce Help Link - https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000007604